# How to retrieve an Animator from a corresponding ViewPropertyAnimator?

Tags: android, animator, viewpropertyanimator

I have defined several different `ViewPropertyAnimator` and I want to bundle them into an `AnimatorSet` in order to apply an "overall" `AnimatorListener` to them.
Since `ViewPropertyAnimator` is not an `Animator` and doesn't have any getter-methods to retrieve its underlying `Animator` how can I accomplish this?

Comment: you can't. That is simply (unfortunately) not supported by the API. What you have to do is check the duration and startDelay for the animations, see which one will be the last to finish and put the listener there.